# nodejs crypto.createhash('sha256') produces different hash for the same response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sha256, cryptojs, etag

I am getting a response from a server every minute and creating a hash with it.
After each fetch from server the hash created is different although they are identical when checked in jsondiff.

```
 let etagh = createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(response.json.data)).digest('hex').toString()
 reply.header('etag',etagh)
```

The response.json.data is always the same but the etagh changes after every fetch call. After every fetch call, the response.json value is updated.

Comment: "*The response.json.data is always the same*" - how do you know that?

Comment: Tried comparing the old , new response objects using lodash.isEquals().
It was true but the JSON.stringify string outputs of these objects was not equal

Comment: So the property order was different? Yeah, that's a known problem of comparing things via `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Ya do you know if I can bypass this somehow?

Comment: Sort the keys if you cannot guarantee their order? Though this is really unusual. Where are you getting these values from?

Comment: JSON.stringify two responses and compare, it must be different. Make sure to define an interface/mapper of the response so as to keep the ordering of keys constant